# How to suppress specific lines in Windows cmd output?

Tags: windows, cmd, filtering

On Windows, I have written a simple bat script that calls another tool. However, this tool outputs a few specific debug lines when using certain options (seems to be a bug in the original code, which I can not/don't want to modify).

Is there a way to suppress lines output by a command that matches a certain pattern (like starting with `DEBUG:` )?

*(FYIO: the tool is `latexdiff.exe`, and there are some `print STDERR "DEBUG:...` lines in the [perl source code](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexdiff/latexdiff) that are not conditional to the `debug` variable and printed everytime the `--flatten` option is used. I don't want to suppress stderr completely either.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
latexdiff.exe 2>&1| findstr /v /b "DEBUG:"
```

The `/v` option basically turns the pattern around, i.e. `findstr.exe` will let everything through, not matching the pattern. The `/b` option simply says that the pattern should occur at the beginning of a line.

The `2>&1` redirects STDERR to STDOUT and is required because, as you said, the lines are written to STDERR, not STDOUT. Note that as a "side effect" all output now is written to STDOUT.

**Update** if there is other output on STDOUT that you need to have, you could do something like this

```
latexdiff.exe old.tex new.tex > diff.tex 2> latexdiff.stderr
type latexdiff.stderr | findstr /v /b "DEBUG:"
```

That is, redirect STDOUT to your diff file, redirect STDERR to some file. Afterwards, you just type the file to see error messages.

You might want to put that into a batch file of it's own, like so:

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM determine a suitable temporary filename
set error_file=%TEMP%\latexdiff.%RANDOM%.stderr
REM run actual diff and save its exit code for later
latexdiff.exe "%~1" "%~2" > "%~3" 2> "%error_file%"
set error_level=%ERRORLEVEL%
REM dump error messages
type "%error_file%" | findstr /v /b "DEBUG:"
REM remove temporary error file and exit with latexdiff's exit code.
del /q "%error_file%"
exit /b %error_level%
```

You can then call it like: `latexdiff_wrapper.cmd old.tex new.tex diff.tex`. Appart from using temporary files, the downside is, that error messages will not appear while processing, but at the very end. If that is not an issue, it shouldn't because the diff should be fast, you might find that solution useful.

Comment: Brilliant. Except for one additional difficulty I didn't think about. `latexdiff.exe` writes its output (a diff file) to stdout, and there seems to be no option to specify an output file explicitly, so the syntax I must use is something like `latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`. Wherever I put your solution (e.g. after `diff.tex`), the debug lines end up in the diff.tex file as well (since, as you wrote, everything is now redirected to stdout). I am not sure how to solve this

Comment: Your updated solution works flawlessly. Setting the correct errorlevel is a nice touch. Thanks a lot !

Comment: For all the cases where useless lines can be removed by matching something at their start, the `findstr /v` solution (chained as necessary) is actually great as it has no dependencies and does not require making a bat file. This really helps.